# check file last modified date

Tags: powershell

I have the following line of code:

```
Get-Item \\MachineNAME\c$\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Registry.pol |
  Foreach {$_.LastWriteTime}
```

This returns the last modified date of a given machine successfully. Using `Out-File` I can write the single result to a text file.

What I would really like to do it read in a list of machine names I have and output all the results to a text file. This would show a list of machines and the last modified date next to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you have one machine per line in c:\temp\computers.txt, something like this could do the trick

```
get-content c:\temp\computers.txt | %{
    $lwt= ls \\$_\c$\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Registry.pol | select -expand lastWriteTime
    echo "$_  :  $lwt" >> c:\temp\results.txt
}
```

Comment: Works as expected. Querying 2000 machines as we speak. Many thanks!

Comment: For such numbers you May want to run this as asynchrones process.  Take a look at `start-job` cmdlet (`gcm "*job" `)